# How do I go about converting a math equation into php?

Tags: php, math

I am not so good at maths and I'm looking to transfer 3 math equations to php functions.

I've tried looking up how to individually do each part of the equation in php but I keep getting strange results so I must be doing something wrong.

Is there a php function for exponential growth?

The image with the equations are here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W17IU.jpg

Thanks

---

For the second equation this is what I have:

```
$rank = 50;

$xp = log(24000 * (2^($rank/6) - 1));

echo $xp;
```

The number is too small for this to be correct. I'm also not sure how to convert the 'ln 2' into PHP. The log() function seemed to come up under 'natural logarithm to php' search.

Comment: can you show us what you've already done?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.math.php might prove to be a good start

Comment: for second equation
`$xp = (24000*(2^($rank/6)-1))/log(2)`

Comment: Please note that `^` is not an exponentiation operator, but a bitwise `XOR` operator. There is an exponentiation operator, `**`, introduced in PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various functions that need to be combined in order to create these equations. The `log` function performs logarithm operations in a base of your choice (or `ln` if you do not provide a base). The `pow` function performs exponentiation.

Your equations would be:

```
function rank($xp) {
    return floor(6 * log((xp * log(2) / 24000 + 1), 2));
}

function xp($rank) {
    return floor(24000 * (pow(2, (rank / 6)) - 1) / log(2));
}

function kills($rank) {
    return floor(xp($rank) / 200);
}
```

There are a few more parentheses there than absolutely needed, for clarity's sake.

Mathematical notations in general are considerably more compact and expressive than most programming languages (not just PHP) due to the fact that you can use any symbol you can think of to represent various concepts. In programming, you're stuck calling functions.

Also, I'm not sure what the various hardcoded numbers represent, or if it makes sense to change them, in the context of the formula, but you might want to think about setting them up as extra parameters to the function. For example:

```
function kills($rank, $killsPerXp = 200) {
    return floor(xp($rank) / $killsPerXp);
}
```

This adds clarity to the code, because it lets you know what the numbers represent. At the same time, it allows you to change the numbers more easily in case you are using them in multiple places.

Comment: Thank you very much Grampa - you went above and beyond to help me with this. Really appreciate it.